# Dynamic incremental load in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I need to create an package which need to do 3 tasks.

It need to compare my source and destination table based on this:

- If new data need to insert data  in destination;
- If data is not there delete;
- If any update in column update as incremental load.

Can we do this dynamically in SSIS? I can pass the source and destination table name in the variable based on this the above process need to done.

Comment: Yes, you can... (in some cases). This question in it's current form is too broad. What did you try, where did you stuck?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/

Comment: You can't handle tables dynamically using data flow tasks. They are using predefined metadata, what you have to set up during design time. You can create packages and/or DFTs programatically using C# for example. If your goal is to move all data from one server to another, you can back up the database on the source and restore it on the destination server. (Note, that this will overwrite all changes on the destination server).

Comment: 1.i'm taking 2 OLE DB Source and joining based on Id using Merge join. 2.using conditional split.3.first condition will insert new data using OLE DB Destination  and second condition will delete the data  Through OLE DB condition.4.For single table it is working fine. i have bulk of tables i need to move data from Test server to Dev server through SSIS.5.In control flow task i'm using Execute SQL Task (sys.tables) to get all tables and connecting this to Foreach Loop Container.6.i'm stuck at merge join dynamic table is not working and OLEDB command DELETE FROM"+ @[User::loop_table] not working

Comment: This makes no sense... Why are you keep deleting your comments (especially when you get answers to them?) At this point, I'll just leave you alone.

Comment: @Pred  sorry Mr.pred I'm new to this site while replying to your  question I'm add some points and removing something that's why deleting and adding my comments  sorry for that one.